# C++ function pointer to class member

Tags: c++, function, std, bind

```
no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::_Binder<std::_Unforced, void (Test::*)(int p_test), Test *, int>" to "std::function<void (Test::*)(int)>" exists
```

So... I don't really know where is my mistake. I didn't used function pointers since last summer but I know that this example used to work back when I was learning std::function and std::bind.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class Test
{
public:
    void display(int p_test)
    {
        std::cout << p_test;
    }
};

void main()
{
    Test t1;

    std::function<void(Test::*)(int)> test = std::bind(&Test::display, &t1, 1);
}
```

Comment: Use `auto` and a lambda function instead of `std::bind()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to bind both parameters of your `display` function (i.e. both the implicit `this` parameter and the explicit `int` parameter), then your `display` member function becomes a `void ()` function after binding

```
std::function<void ()> test = std::bind(&Test::display, &t1, 1);
test();
```

If you bind just the `this` parameter, then it'll become a `void (int)` function

```
std::function<void (int)> test = std::bind(&Test::display, &t1, std::placeholders::_1);
test(42);
```

If you don't want to bind any parameters, then your `display` function is a function with two parameters of `Test *` and `int` type

```
std::function<void (Test *, int)> test = &Test::display;
test(&t1, 123);
```

So, you need to decide first which parameters you want to bind and which parameters you want to keep unbound.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use std::function like this.

```
std::function<void()>
```

As @user0042 suggested, `auto` would do the job here, but I think you want to **store** a functor. Then `std::function` is the right way for this.
`auto` won't help, if you want to store a functor in a class or something like that. `std::bind` is a little bit of cryptic, indeed, but I don't think a `lambda` is necessary to get around this.

Comment: Not my downvote. But if you used the OP's `bind` call, then you'd need `std::function<void()>`, not your `std::function<void(int)>`. The OP's `bind` binds *both* parameters.